# How to get column names with ODP.NET DataAdapter filling a DataSet in C#?

Tags: c#, odp.net

I'm filling a Data Table use ODP.NET's OracleDataAdapter. I'd like to pass along the column headers too. Any idea how to go about this? Thanks!

```
OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(oc);

            oda.Fill(dt);

            FileInfo outFile = new FileInfo(outputPath + "out.xlsx");
            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(outFile))
            {


                //Create the worksheet
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Netstat");
                for (int row = 1; row <= dt.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 1; column <= dt.Columns.Count; column++)
                    {
                        ws.Cells[row, column].Value = dt.Rows[row - 1][column - 1];
                    }
                }

                pck.Save();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am sure if you loop on all datatable's datacolumn you can get out fieldname of each column.

Comment: The DataTable's Columns-Collection will have all selected fields of yor DataAdapter's SelectCommand atomatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you are filling the `DataSet` but if you use the "standard way" i.e.

```
string MyTableName = "customers";
MyAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet, MyTableName);
```

THEN the column names are already in the `DataSet` i.e. `MyDataSet.Tables [MyTableName].Columns[0].ColumnName` .

This is a standard ADO.NET feature, nothing special about ODP.NET - see the MSDN reference at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnname.aspx

**EDIT - AFTER the OP added source code:**

In your code you aren't using `DataSet` but `DataTable` so you can access the column names by `dt.Columns[column].ColumnName` .